# Наибольшая величина выигрыша

Tags: алгоритм, динамическое-программирование

Задана лента шириной в одну клетку и длиной в n клеток. На каждой клетке написано некоторое целое число. Играют два игрока, которые ходят поочерёдно. За один ход игрок отрезает от ленты одну из крайних клеток и забирает её. Игра останавливается, когда лента заканчивается. Выигрыш игрока равен сумме чисел на находящихся у него клетках ленты. Необходимо определить величину выигрыша, которую может себе гарантировать игрок, начинающий игру первым. (Это тот размер выигрыша, который первый игрок обеспечит себе при любой игре второго игрока.)
Хотелось бы услышать алгоритм решения с подробным пояснением
Сам придумал такой алгоритм:всё закидываю в вектор, отрезаю к примеру первый элемент вектора,и смотрю сумму 2 элемента и последнего минус отрезанный первый и сравниваю эту сумму,если бы я отрезал последний элемент с суммой первого и предпоследнего минус последний. То значение которое меньше считаю истинным и отрезаю полностью элемент.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<fstream> 
#include<algorithm> 
#include<vector> 
#include<iomanip> 

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream fin("input.txt");
    ofstream fout("output.txt");

    int n;
    fin >> n;
    int i;
    vector<int> len;
    int res = 0;
    while (fin >> i)
    {
        len.push_back(i);
    }

    int j = 0;
    while (!len.empty())
    {
        if (len.size() == 1)
        {
            res = len[0];
            break;
        }
        if (len.size() == 2)
        {
            if (len[0] > len[1])
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                {
                    res += len[0];
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    res += len[1];
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                {
                    res += len[1];
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    res += len[0];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (len.size() > 2)
        {
            if (j % 2 == 0)
            {
                if ((len[1] + len[len.size() - 1]) - len[0] < (len[0] + len[len.size() - 1]) - len[len.size() - 1])
                {
                    res += len[0];
                    len.erase(len.begin() + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    res += len[len.size() - 1];
                    len.erase(len.begin() + len.size() - 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((len[1] + len[len.size() - 1]) - len[0] < (len[0] + len[len.size() - 1]) - len[len.size() - 1])
                {
                    //res += len[0]; 
                    len.erase(len.begin() + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    //res += len[len.size() - 1]; 
                    len.erase(len.begin() + len.size() - 1);
                }
            }
        }


        j++;
    }
    fout << res;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: За вас никто задачу решать не будет, думайте.

Comment: Так я вот привёл своего решения, оно не проходит пару тестов, в чем ошибка хотелось бы узнать

Comment: Что ж вы его сразу не показали?

Comment: Я его сразу показал. Вы невнимательный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня левый индекс `r`, правый `c`, т.к. это при отладке это были ряд и колонка в таблице.

На куске ленты от индекса `r` до `c` игрок может взять левую клетку `A[r]`, тогда останется кусок с суммой `S[r+1..c]`, из которой второй игрок заберёт как можно больше, или правую клетку `A[c]`, тогда останется кусок с суммой `S[r..c-1]`, из которой второй игрок опять же заберёт как можно больше.

Пусть лучший результат для описанного фрагмента `Table[r, c]`, `с>=r`, начальные значения по диагонали понятно какие.

Будем заполнять заполнять таблицу (треугольную) по диагоналям, каждый элемент получается с помощью выбора лучшего результата при ходе из левой и нижней клеток. В коде `d` - номер диагонали.
Delphi.

```
 function BestCut(A: array of Integer): Integer;
   var
      n, i, d, p, r, c: Integer;
      Sums: array of Integer;
      Table: array of array of Integer;
   begin
     n := Length(A);
     SetLength(Sums, n + 1);
     Sums[0] := 0;
     for i := 1 to n do
       Sums[i] := Sums[i - 1] + A[i - 1];
     SetLength(Table, n, n);
     for i := 0 to n- 1 do
       Table[i, i] := A[i];

     for d := 1 to n - 1 do
       for r := 0 to n - d - 1 do begin
         c := d + r;
         Table[r, c] := Max(A[r] + (Sums[c + 1] - Sums[r + 1] - Table[r + 1, c]),
                            A[c] + (Sums[c] - Sums[r] - Table[r, c - 1]));
       end;

     Result := Table[0, n-1];
   end;


  BestCut([3, 7, 5, 4, 6]) даёт 14 
  BestCut([3, 7, 5, 4]) даёт 11
```

Добавлено: код автора вопроса на С++

```
int *sums = new int[n+1];
sums[0] = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    sums[i] = sums[i - 1] + len[i - 1];
vector<vector<long long>>M(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        M[i].push_back(0);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    M[i][i]=len[i];
for(int d=1;d<n;d++)
    for(int r=0;r<=n-d-1;r++)
        {
            int c=d+r;
            if((len[r] + (sums[c + 1] - sums[r + 1] - M[r + 1][c])) >
                      (len[c] + (sums[c] - sums[r] - M[r][c - 1])))
                M[r][c]=len[r] + (sums[c + 1] - sums[r + 1] - M[r + 1][c]);
            else
                M[r][c]=len[c] + (sums[c] - sums[r] - M[r][c - 1]);
        }

fout<<M[0][n-1];
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, попытаюсь сейчас разобраться и реализовать

Comment: всё реализовал,сейчас прикреплю код. огромное спасибо

Comment: добавил код на с++